# Atualizar dados no ListView com ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Tenho um ListView que será preenchido com alguns dados diferentes, que podem ou não serem chamados (simultâneamente ou não).

Exemplo:
O usuário pode adicionar e remover ingredientes de um produto. Porém, pode somente remover ou somente adicionar.

Caso ele faça os dois, o código para tratar seria esse:

```
ListView liv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lista_sel);
AdaptadorItem adapter;

if (!objetos_add.isEmpty()){
    adater = new AdaptadorItem (contexto, R.layout.item_obs_carrinho, objetos_add);
    liv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

if (!objetos_rem.isEmpty()){
    adater = new AdaptadorItem (contexto, R.layout.item_obs_carrinho, objetos_rem);
    liv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

O problema é que não sei como incrementar o que já existe em *adapter* e adicionar ao *ListView*. Do jeito que está ele apaga o que foi colocado no ListView no primeiro *if* e só coloca o que vem no segundo *if*.

Já busquei sobre *notifyDataSetChanged()*, mas para o meu caso, onde uso um adaptador personalizado com **extends ArrayAdapter**, não achei solução.

objetos_add e objetos_rem são  ArrayList < String[ ] >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O *adapter* só deve ser criado uma vez.

```
ListView liv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lista_sel);
AdaptadorItem adapter;
ArrayList<String> objetos = new ArrayList<String>();

adater = new AdaptadorItem (contexto, R.layout.item_obs_carrinho, objetos);
```

Quando quiser adicionar/remover itens, adicione-os/remova-os do ArrayList usado quando criou o *adapter* e chame o método `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
private void addObjetos(ArrayList<String> objetos_add){
    for(String objeto : objetos_add){
        objetos.add(objeto)
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void removeObjetos(ArrayList<String> objetos_rem){
    for(String objeto : objetos_rem){
        objetos.remove(objeto)
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```